# How to manage NX 15 package dependency list in the same way as pre-15?

Tags: node.js, typescript, monorepo, nrwl-nx, nrwl

In versions prior to NX 15 I found that NX's automagic additions of dependencies to work very well for my use case.

However, with NX 15 came a change, see: https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/12675#issuecomment-1297000614, which is lamented in another issue as well: https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/12660. This change is a problem for my use case.

My use case is this: I have libraries A and B in an NX repository. I publish those to a registry and then consume them in project C. In the libraries A and B I want to only specify high-level dependencies like NestJS as peerDependencies in the package.json since these libs will roll up into a consuming project where I'll manage versions. I don't want to pin versions in these libs because it will cause version conflict challenges across the consuming projects.

What I'm seeing with NX 15 is that all dependencies of dependencies get pinned in the published package.json file to exact versions. Also, I've noticed that depending on which library I build first, other libraries might have new packages added to them with pinned versions (because some libs depend on other libs), so I can't simply list all dependencies as `peerDependencies` with `*` because they seem to change in a pattern I don't recognize.

So, ultimately I'm wondering how I can get back to pre-NX-15 style dependency management without having to go fully manual? (I see one project switched to manual: https://github.com/robinpellegrims/pellegrims/issues/181#issuecomment-1336422869)

Comment: I recommend adding the linked comments as quotes in addition to the link to make the question more self contained.